# There is some kind of DataSnap XE TServerMethods setup?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, datasnap

I'm trying some TServerMethods and all of those interact with my
Firebird DB.

I don't want to get the SQLConnection.DBXConnection in every method
that I'll create, but I want to inherit that behavior from a superclass
that will setup a protected DBXConnection everytime my ServerMethod is
called, inside a inherited Create, or something like that.

I could find any way to do that besides calling my procedure
SetupDBXConnection everytime. There's some way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I must have forgotten to say, but i'll used Andreano Lanusse's article (http://www.andreanolanusse.com/pt/publicando-providers-durante-o-registro-dinamico-de-datasnap-server-class/) to get the same effect publishin TServerMethods at runtime, and it worked! 

But i can't setup a constructor, because it doesn't work.

Comment: All your SetupDBXConnection has to have is `If not SQLConnection.Connected then SQLConnection.Connected = True;` to achieve the optimisation you want.